# What book should I read to learn how to deal with networking issues?

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

I run into wireless router and networking issues very often. I'd like to finally just read a book on how to trouble and diagnose problems, using tools like ifconfig, editing files like /etc/network/interfaces, and whatever. Any recommendations?

Comment: Really, the best source is internet. Why not post your details here or ubuntuforums.org and someone will be be able to help you?

Comment: papukaija is right, it's hard to tell what you need to learn if you want to learn *everything* possible in this topic ... it would be better to have one or more problems you have/had as questions, so people can answer what you can read/learn to solve issues like that/those ...

Comment: I don't know. I've searched forums a lot before, and usually people just say edit this and run this command -- it's a good way to fix problems but not really to learn how to understand what's going on.

Comment: If you want to know why something works you can always ask here or on [Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you may want to look at Amazon.com for books on the subject. Many times there are used books at discount price that will give you want you need.

I found a "Linux Network Administration" that normally lists for ~35USD for 12!

Hope this helps.

Randy3011